# PHP LDAP Binding issue: Unable to bind to server: Internal (implementation specific) error

Tags: php, binding, ldap

I am new in LDAP and I have issue with binding.
Here is my code:

```
$con = ldap_connect(11.11.11.11); // LDAP server is placed at another machine
ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_bind($con, "cn=Michael,cn=Users,DC=example,DC=com", "password");
```

Looks like everything is fine with connection. The error appears on ldap_bind:

> ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Internal (implementation
>   specific) error

I have tried to google this error but found nothing. When I change DN to incorrect on purpose another error apears that says "bad credentials". It means everything is fine with DN and password. Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cn of "Users" (cn=Users) is likely to be your organizational unit (ou).
Have you tried the DN: "cn=Michael,**ou**=Users,DC=example,DC=com" ?